# qsort with size 0 undefined?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, qsort

I have a report, unconfirmed by me but from a reliable source, that the code

```
qsort(a, n, sizeof *a, cmpfunc);
```

is compiled by a modern version of gcc *as if* it had been written

```
if(n == 0)
    __builtin_trap();
qsort(a, n, sizeof *a, cmpfunc);
```

Evidently it is believed that calling `qsort` with `n == 0` is undefined behavior.

*[Edit: The whole premise here was found to be false; see "Update 2" below.]*

It has been pointed out that Posix explicitly blesses the `n == 0` case, <s>but evidently no extant version of the C Standard does</s>.

So the obvious questions are:

1. Is calling `qsort` with `n = 0` actually undefined behavior in C?
2. Is every program which ever calls `qsort` with arbitrary `n` truly obliged to check for `n == 0` and not call `qsort` in that case?
3. Why would gcc perform this "optimization"?  Even if you believe that calling `qsort` with `n == 0` is undefined, this would seem to marginally slow down every *non* undefined program.

Textbook implementations of quicksort (which, I know, `qsort` is not required to be) pretty much can't not handle `n = 0` correctly.  I wonder if gcc's behavior here is trying to guard against a `qsort` implementation that somehow does something much worse than a `__builtin_trap` if the initial call has `n == 0`?

---

Update: Thanks for the responses so far.  <s>It sounds like gcc is in the wrong here.</s> As I said, I haven't confirmed [this result](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2022-October/032096.html) myself, but I'm [trying to find out](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2022-October/032097.html) which version of gcc and with which optimization flags the issue was observed.

---

Update 2: The original report I referred to was [in error](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2022-October/032107.html).  Two key clarifications:

1. gcc was in fact checking for `a == 0`, *not* `n == 0`.  This is obviously a completely different kettle of fish: As this thread (and others) has confirmed, calling `qsort` on a null pointer is considerably more problematic, and almost certainly formally undefined.
2. The compilation in question included the `-fsanitize=undefined` and `-fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error` flags, so *of course* gcc was being stringent about checking for inadvertent null pointers (and even at a cost to efficiency).

Sorry for the misinformation and runaround.  I'm afraid this question is now in the realm of "not reproducible or was caused by a typo", and I have put one close vote in the hopper on that basis.

For what it's worth, the gcc version was 12.2.1.

Comment: Could it be an instrumentation because of a constrained range for `n`? Recently I used a compiler that silently checked all usages of enumerated values. Anyway, a confirmation would be great, for example as an example at godbolt's Compiler Explorer.

Comment: _Posix explicitly blesses the `n == 0` case, but evidently no extant version of the C Standard does._ C11 **7.22.5 Searching and sorting utilities** [p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.5p1):  These utilities make use of a comparison function to search or sort arrays of unspecified type. Where an argument declared as `size_t nmemb` specifies the length of the array for a function, **`nmemb` can have the value zero on a call to that function**; the comparison function is not called, a search finds no matching element, and sorting performs no rearrangement.

Comment: MSVC is benign. With 0 or 1 elements the comparator function isn't called, although their [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/qsort?view=msvc-170) states "`qsort` calls the `compare` routine one or more times". However it also says "if `width` is **less than zero**, the invalid parameter handler is invoked"

Comment: The quoted text by @LanguageLawyer is unambiguous and largely settles the discussion.  It might be dodgy passing a null pointer; it depends on the interpretation of _"Pointer arguments on such a call shall still have valid values, as described in 7.1.4."_ (where §7.1.4 is a set of general requirements on arguments to library functions).  Is NULL a valid pointer value?

Comment: I think you are referring to this post on the TZ mailing list? https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2022-October/032096.html

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In the context of section 7.1.4, a null pointer is not valid argument to a library function call unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow the section.

Comment: @IanAbbott Well spotted. :-)  And I am posting to that thread now.

Comment: @SteveSummit Me too (again)!

Comment: @IanAbbott — yes, I'm sure the discussion is in relation to the TZ mailing list.  The timing and content is too similar for it to be accidental.  I agree that passing a null pointer is probably UB — but passing zero elements and a non-null pointer to valid memory (so not a completely random non-null pointer) should be OK.  In the context of TZ, the obvious test is `if (nlinks > 1) qsort(…);` (instead of the proposed `if (nlinks != 0) qsort(…);`) — there is no need to sort a 1-element array (or a 0-element array, especially not one identified by a null pointer).

Comment: Note that [C99 ¶7.10.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.20.5) has the preamble remarks also in C11 and C17/C18.

Comment: This question is now moot because the reliable source misread the assembly language produced by GCC. Replace `if(n == 0)` with `if(a == NULL)` for the corrected reading. See https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2022-October/032107.html

Comment: @IanAbbott Indeed; see "Update 2" in edited question.

Comment: @SteveSummit I have also added a close vote for the same reason.

Comment: @SteveSummit, I concur that the question was inspired by a situation that would warrant closure for reason of typo / unreproducibility.  I'm not sure I would otherwise have said the same about the resulting question itself, but since you're suggesting such a closure of your own question, I have added the third vote needed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It hurts to close my own question, but it also hurts to have wasted people's time on this.  And questions contrary to fact, or based on false premises, like this one, are endlessly and meta confusing, so they're really best closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Is calling qsort with n = 0 actually undefined behavior in C?

It is well-defined behavior in every version of the language.

> 2. Is every program which ever calls qsort with arbitrary n truly obliged to check for n == 0 and not call qsort in that case?

The application programmer's source need not perform any such check. As for the behavior of the generated program, the `qsort` library function shouldn't call the comparison function internally, so it's essentially the same thing as not calling `qsort` at all, equivalent to a no-op.

> Why would gcc perform this "optimization"? Even if you believe that calling qsort with n == 0 is undefined, this would seem to marginally slow down every non undefined program.

Because n == 0 is a special, well-defined case which allows compiler optimizations (not to call the function). Though of course an extra branch is not necessarily an optimization.

---

Sources:

C17 7.22.5.2

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

C17 7.22.5 emphasis mine:

> These utilities make use of a comparison function to search or sort arrays of unspecified
> type. **Where an argument declared as `size_t nmemb` specifies the length of the array for a function, `nmemb` can have the value zero on a call to that function; the comparison
> function is not called, a search finds no matching element, and sorting performs no
> rearrangement.** Pointer arguments on such a call shall still have valid values, as described
> in 7.1.4.

Comment: Aren't "Yes" and "Or rather, `qsort` shouldn't call the comparison function" effectively contradictory answers to question 2?  Based on everything else stated here, I would expect the answer to be "No".

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Not really. There's no requirement that `qsort` isn't called, just that the call should boil down to a no-op. It's all clarified by the quoted 7.22.5.

Comment: But question 2 asks if *callers* of `qsort` are obligated to check for `n == 0` and not call `qsort`.  Your argument then implies that the answer is "No", because callers do *not* have to explicitly check for `n == 0`--`qsort` should handle that case.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Ah, well I guess that depends on by "program" you mean the application source or the compiler-generated binary. I'll clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the legwork, @Lundin.  I (blush) hadn't checked the Standard myself, but was relying on the research of other respondents on the original mailing list thread who hadn't been able to find anything.

Comment: Re “It is well-defined behavior in every version of the language.”: As [dbush’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74208823/298225) indicates, the 1990 C standard did not contain the wording stating `nmemb` can be zero. But, like other versions, it did define an array type as “a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects…,” so, for `qsort` to “sort an array of `nmemb` objects”, it would have to be given a nonempty array.

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, the most recent version of the C standard as well as POSIX explicitly allows for the `nmemb` argument to be 0.  However, this language is missing from the C89 standard.

Section 4.10.5 of [C89](https://web.archive.org/web/20161223125339/http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt) (equivalent to §7.10.5 of C90) doesn't contain the additional paragraphs before the specifications for `bsearch` or `qsort` that allows for this.  So it's *possible* that compiling in strict C89 mode could generate the effective code in the question.

The most recent gcc in C89 mode doesn't show the offending behavior:

https://godbolt.org/z/YhKoGEre7

But other versions conceivably could.  I haven't checked them all.

UPDATE:

According to this posting, which triggered the initial question:

https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2022-October/032096.html

And this one in response to it:

https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2022-October/032107.html

The behavior in question was observed on gcc 12.2 with the `-fsanitize=undefined` option, **and** there was an error on the part of the person reporting the behavior in reading the assembly.  The above godbolt link shows the following disassembly with the given compiler and options:

```
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        movsx   rbx, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.Lubsan_data0
        call    __ubsan_handle_nonnull_arg
        mov     ecx, OFFSET FLAT:cmpfunc
        mov     edx, 4
        mov     rsi, rbx
        mov     edi, 0
        call    qsort
        mov     eax, 0
```

The check is actually looking to see if `base` is NULL, not if `nmemb` is 0.  And in that case, it *is* undefined behavior.

Comment: Hmmm, is there really any "issue" in the question?

Comment: @klutt That was a bit vague.  Updated.

Comment: I haven't managed to reproduce the issue with godbolt either.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: The C99 rationale only mentions that C99 has clarified the requirements and use of the functions. There's no mentioning of the size zero case being explicit UB nor was it listed in the C90 UB list. But maybe this was a quality of implementation thing in C90 indeed.

Comment: `nmemb` is explicitly allowed to be zero since C99 (see [N852](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n852.htm) and [N872](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n872.htm)). But I guess the change is considered editorial.

Answer (score 4):

From POSIX standard (emphasize is mine):

> [CX] **The functionality described on this reference page
> is aligned with the ISO C standard**. Any conflict between the
> requirements described here and the ISO C standard is unintentional.
> This volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 defers to the ISO C standard.
>
> The `qsort()` function shall sort an array of `nel` objects,
> the initial element of which is pointed to by `base`. The size of each
> object, in bytes, is specified by the `width` argument. **If the `nel`
> argument has the value zero, the comparison function pointed to by
> `compar` shall not be called and no rearrangement shall take place**.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, the C standard library function for `qsort` is required to handle a size of zero properly.

But that is from a programmers point of view. The C standard does not dictate anything about the produced machine code except that it should behave the way it should.

It's perfectly valid for a C compiler to produce a binary file that calls a sorting function that does NOT handle sizes of 0 properly, as long as it adds a zero check before it. But I cannot find anything in the C89 standard that allows UB if the size is zero.

In practice, the additional text in the specification does not add much. The relevant part is this:

> `nmemb` can have the value zero on a call to that function; the comparison function is not called

That means that this snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {

   puts("foobar"); // To see if this function is executed

   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main (void) {

   int values[1] = {42};

   qsort(values, 0, sizeof *values, cmpfunc);
}
```

is guaranteed to NOT print "foobar" if you compile with C99 or later. But if you compile with C89, it may happen. Or not. But this code does not invoke undefined behavior in either C89 or a later version.

John Bollinger made an interesting point in the comment section

> Absent the explicit specification that the second argument may be 0, I could make an argument for that being UB. It would revolve around the fact that the second argument is required to be the length of the array pointed to be the first argument, and C not having zero-length arrays. But I would nevertheless expect every C implementation to handle the situation in the natural way described by later versions of the spec.

There is a little bit of wiggle room to make the interpretation that it's UB without the explicit requirement that size zero is allowed. However, the C standard explicitly states many things as UB, but not this.

My personal opinion (and I would love to know if there is any official consensus on this matter) is that if that the specs are vague, but not explicitly stated as UB, then the compiler should NOT use the ambiguity for optimizations. Doing so would be [malicious compliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malicious_compliance)

Comment: Absent the explicit specification that the second argument may be 0, I could make an argument for that being UB. It would revolve around the fact that the second argument is required to be the length of the array pointed to be the first argument, and C not having zero-length arrays.  But I would nevertheless expect every C implementation to handle the situation in the natural way described by later versions of the spec.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Good point. Updated.